# How to sort a range with over 1500 rows?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public r1 As Range, rOb As Range, rDat As Range
Set r1 = Range(db.Range("B3"), db.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) ' about 1500 rows
Set rOb = Range(db.Range("B3"), db.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rDat = Range(db.Range("G3"), db.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

r1.Sort Key1:=rOb
'Or
r1.Sort Key1:=rDat
```

Only about 900 rows are sorted. The rest are NOT.
Sometimes, the sort doesn't work at all.
Also tried:

```
r1.Sort Key1:=Range(db.Range("G3"), db.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

The same result

Comment: Do your 1500 rows have data in column I all the way down? Since your sort is based on the last cell of column I, maybe it's missing data. Try `msgbox r1.address` to make sure you're sorting on the full range.

Comment: @nutsch, ThankYou. Column I is almost empty. I see the point. Maybe you should write the comment as answer, so it vould be possible to vote and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your range picks the last row. If Column I has blank cells at the bottom, your range is incomplete.

Try using

```
Set r1 = db.Range("B3").currentregion
```

or

```
r1 = Range(db.Range("B3"), db.Range("I" & db.cells(Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).row)
```

where you set "B" to a column without blanks in your data